# G_M not correctly

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to implement the Marker Cluster with the below code is not working. When i am trying to execute this, it is displaying the Marker but it is not Clustering the Markers. I have tried to fix this but i failed. Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: To me it seems like jquery is missing: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, but maybe that's just in the snippet you provided

Comment: yes sir it's just the snippet that i provided, because you need , the code php of ( get_data_google_api.php) in the URL (http://localhost/innotech/inc/get_data_google_api.php),  because it is the URL who return all data who i need in my map from my database  thank you sir

Comment: @Orlandster i hope that you understand me sir

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (provide sample/test data returned by your localhost URL, preferable making the code snippet work)

Comment: markersData is not an array of `google.maps.Marker` objects, duplicate of [Google Maps MarkerClusterer Not Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234976/google-maps-markerclusterer-not-clustering) or [Google Maps v3 MarkerClusterer not Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286524/google-maps-v3-markerclusterer-not-clustering) or [Google Maps - Marker Cluster issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463560/google-maps-marker-cluster-issue)

Comment: sir @geocodezip , what is the object's who i will use , because i don't know it , even i saw the exemples who you mention it for me .
sir how i can manipulate my javascript code . i'm a beginner in this field , some push from you will help me a lot

Comment: @geocodezip about what you said ( (provide sample/test data returned by your localhost URL, preferable making the code snippet work) ) ,i hope that, but  i can't , because the problem is i don't know how , as i mentioned i'm a beginner , i hope that learn from you sir , if there is a solution without to need the code snippet , i will thankful .... thanks for your time

Comment: any help please  ?? : @obojdi

Comment: @kjy112  any help sir ??

Comment: @Anup  any help sir , i'm really confused ??

Answer (score 0):

I haven't time to examine this in close detail but:

```
    createMarker(latlng, Route, Agence, Secteur, CodeClient, PrecisionGPS, Latitude, Longitude, BarCode, PrenomClient, NumAdresse, Tel, Whatsapp, NbrFrigo, OpenAm, CloseAm, OpenPm, ClosePm, OpenAmVen, CloseAmVen, OpenPmVen, ClosePmVen, OpenAmDim, CloseAmDim, OpenPmDim, ClosePmDim, IMEI, Date_Added);

      // marker position is added to bounds variable
      bounds.extend(latlng); 

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersData,{imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
   }
```

Two things here:

1. Markers need to be pushed into an array to be used by MarkerClusterer,markersData. I can't see that happening?
2. MarkerClusterer needs to be outside the marker creation loop, when you have all the markers in an array.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed my code as you recommended, but the problem still

Answer (score 0):

Hugh nailed it. You only need to create one MarkerClusterer, then add your array of markers to it after you've created all the markers. That's about it.

Take a look at the examples:

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus/examples

Comment: i saw all the examples sir , but it not show me what i want, they still display juste markers , sir i use a json data in my exemple who return all data for my map  , i explain the code of all my files in the discription of my probleme  @user1469420